# how can i get a file path from URL object

Tags: java, file-io

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        URL url = getClass().getResource("CustomerDedupeRules.xml");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(url.getPath()));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
```

i am trying to update an xml file which exists in my classes folder. but i am getting file not found exception if i use url.getPath() or url.getFile().
the code is working fine if i hardcode the file path instead of using URL object.
please suggest me what is wrong with my approach.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can obtain a File from a classpath resource. Because a classpath resource is typically packaged up in a JAR file. And IMHO it doesn't make sense to update a JAR file that is currently in use.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this file ? If it is inside a jar, you should use the [openStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method to get access to the contents. If it is not inside a jar, print the absolute path of the File using [getAbsolutePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) and verify if it exists.

Comment: file is not part of jar. it exists in the file system. openstream() is working fine. i am reading the file and checking it before updating(i have not pasted that code here, but i am doing it successfully). URL.getPath() returns file path as: C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%206.0\webapps\Dedupe\WEB-INF\classes\com\infor\dedupe\Column_Mappings.xml    : spaces are represented as %20 with url.getPath(). i think that is why i am getting file not found exception

Comment: Whitespaces are fine. The file should still be read. Perhaps the problem is that whitespaces are URL encoded and the File API cannot understand that. Can you try decoding the String and feeding it into the File API ?